# Can spells that target creatures affect (damage) the layers of a Prismatic Wall spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, wall

I know that spells, in general, state what they can target - which is often only creatures. Spells which can target other things like objects (as in Fire Bolt) or magical effects (as in Dispel Magic) say that they do in their descriptions.

However, this leaves a seeming oversight specifically with the Prismatic Wall spell - which is obviously not a creature.

So my question is, do spells that usually target creatures have the ability to harm the Prismatic Wall spell?

As a more specific example for only a single layer, the Cone of Cold spell is used in previous editions as the specific spell that destroys the red layer of Prismatic Wall. However, in this edition Cone of Cold states that "each creature" in the area makes the save, and that "a creature" in the area takes the damage. Could Cone of Cold destroy the red layer of a Prismatic Wall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How do you want your spells to work?

In the PHB section on Spellcasting, we see that:

> A typical spell requires you to pick one or more targets to be affected by the spell’s magic. A spell's description tells you whether the spell targets creatures, objects, or a point of origin for an area of effect...

Your initial assumption is:

> I know that spells, in general, state what they can target - which is often only creatures...do spells that usually target creatures have the ability to harm the Prismatic Wall spell?

It seems to me that you are conflating the issue of choosing a spell *target* (what must be present for the spell to be cast) with resolving what classes of things a spell may legitimately *affect* after it is cast.  **Just because a spell requires you to choose 'a target to be affected by the spell's magic' does not mean that this target is the *only* thing that the spell affects or can harm.**

In particular, for 'area of effect' spells (like *cone of cold*), the target you *choose* is the spell's point of origin; after this, the spell can then affect things within its 'area of effect' without you having to choose them and without them being specified as targets.  These other things *might* be called 'targets' in the spell description, or they might not.  For example, *[fireball](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fireball)* explicitly says that it can damage creatures, and calls them targets, but it also explicitly says that it ignites flammable objects, while *not* calling them targets.  *[Flame Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flame-strike)*, on the other hand, explicitly damages creatures, but the creatures are *not* called targets.

As above, "A spell's description tells you whether the spell targets...a point of origin for an area of effect".  **For an area of effect spell, the only target you choose is the point of origin**; for what the spell *affects* you need to read the spell description.

*Cone of Cold* says:

> A blast of cold air erupts from your hands. Each creature in a 60-foot cone must make a Constitution saving throw. A creature takes 8d8 cold damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

We know that this is an area of effect spell, so the *target you choose* is the point of origin of the cone.  For what else can be affected by the spell, we need to read the spell description.  We can see that the spell explicitly affects creatures, but could it affect other things?

Here you have a fundamental choice to make - **are you reading the spell description in a prescriptive way or a descriptive way?**  A prescriptive reading would take the spell description to mean that it does exactly and only what it says it does.  A descriptive reading would use the '[no flavor in spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78012/is-there-flavor-text-in-dd-5e-spells)' principle to construct other effects not explicitly spelled out so long as they were not excluded by the spell description or other rules, following the principle of 'the DM describes the results of your actions'.

Both of these approaches are RAW, and both have their advantages and disadvantages.  The prescriptive approach has the advantage of being very clear in interpretation and more uniformly applied across DMs, which is important in situations like Adventure League play.  Unfortunately, in cases like this (can a *cone of cold* damage the red layer of *prismatic wall*?) a prescriptive reading produces the result of '[the rules are stupid, so ignore them](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/199261/23547)'.  A prescriptive reading admits that yes, the spell produces a blast of air that is objectively cold, but then says that this blast has no further effects because the spell does not explicitly state them.

A descriptive reading, on the other hand, is more subjective.  Since the spell says that it produces a 'blast of cold air', each DM will have to determine what the subsequent effects of this blast are, because it is just as much an effect of the spell as the explicit damage to creatures is.  However, the descriptive approach has the advantage of using RAW to get the much more satisfying result of the *cone* being able to take down the *wall*.

How cold is this blast of cold air?  It is so cold that it does 8d8 cold damage.  What kinds of things would this damage?  Anything in its area of effect that is *capable of being damaged by cold*.  We know that it damages creatures, because the spell description says that it damages creatures, but **it does *not* say it damages *only* creatures,** so with a descriptive approach we are free to consider other possibilities.

Can this cold damage objects?  No, because objects are immune to effects that cause Constitution saves (as per the general rule on PHB 185).

Can this blast of cold air cause environmental effects?  Could it frost over the surface of a water trough, cause condensation droplets to form on beer steins, or blow loose papers off a desk?  A descriptive reading would say sure, the DM describes the results of the players' actions and any of these effects are fair game, so long as they don't rise to the level of 'causing damage to an object' which is prohibited as above.  A prescriptive reading would say that none of these effects are possible because they aren't explicitly permitted by the spell.

The red wall of *Prismatic Wall* is neither a creature, nor an object; it is a spell effect.  Spell effects are special, and in their descriptions they state what they can be damaged by, if anything.  A spell effect that does not specifically say it can be damaged by cold would not be damaged, but **a spell effect that says it *can* be damaged by cold will be.**

*Prismatic Wall* says:

> Red: ...The layer can be destroyed by dealing at least 25 cold damage to it.

When the *cone of cold* intersects with the *wall*, we have a spell effect whose description says it does 8d8 cold damage overlapping in space with a spell effect that says it is destroyed by 25 points of cold damage.  Because the *wall* is not a creature, it does not get a save.  Because the *wall* is not an object, it is not immune.  Because the *wall* says it can be damaged by cold, it can be.  96% of the time, the *wall* will be brought down by the first *cone of cold* cast.

Thus, a descriptive reading of the spell gives us the answer that we intuitively want anyway, and still supports the RAW framework of the game.  I think that is pretty useful.

Comment: Interesting that objects are auto-immune to damage requiring a Con save (or any save really other than Str or Dex). This explains why the spell does not mention Objects being damaged -- that rule is rather obscurely tucked away in the middle of a paragraph, and likely often overlooked, so people reading that Cone can target objects could miss this, and deal damage to them (even if they knew "why mention it at all if the are immune, there must be an exception" is also a reasonable result there).

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin It is a bit strange that the rule about objects being immune to non-(Str/Dex) save effects is not in, or at least also in, the DMG section on "Objects and Damage Types" (247).  I certainly didn't come across it browsing the PHB, but rather in questions on this site like [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124731/how-does-shatter-damage-objects-if-objects-are-immune-to-con-save-effects)

Comment: I think the tricky thing is exactly the same as with Shatter: objects would be immune if they would need to make a Con save (due to the general rule), but the spell does not call for them to make a Con save, so does that mean they are not immune if they are in the area? If that were so, why would Shatter need to call out explictily that objects take damage?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Given the context of "Objects...can be affected by physical and magical attacks **much like creatures can**," and to avoid circularity, I parse "Objects always fail Strength and Dexterity saving throws, and they are immune to effects that require other saves." as "Objects always fail Strength and Dexterity saving throws, and they are immune to effects that [would] require other saves [of creatures]."  Thus if _cone_ would require a Con save of a creature, an object would be immune to the effect of the cold.  1/2

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin 2/2 If *shatter* requires a Con save for a creature, objects are immune (general rule) except that _non-magic_ objects take the damage because the spell says they do (specific over general) while magical objects do not (general Con save rule).

Comment: @Kirt I believe overall that this is a better and more comprehensive answer than the other, as it describes a reasonable interpretation of RAW that results in what appears to be RAI. I had some concerns since I had always heard that [spells only do what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/107647/60984), but in looking that up I also saw [some support](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/112460/60984) for the idea of a descriptive reading introducing additional spell effects. I did understand that spells like Cone of Cold only target points - that was just poor wording on my part. 1/2

Comment: @Kirt Regardless, I think I'll accept this answer if no better answer presents itself soon. Side note: I believe your section on brown mold is incorrect, and that your answer doesn't need it. This is because hazards and traps would likely just be one or more objects - and we know things trees/inanimate plants are objects, so mold isn't really a stretch. Also, the brown mold doesn't need to be dealt cold damage, it just needs to be "exposed to an effect that deals cold damage" - which would be a specific rule in the mold's text overriding any general rule of spells not affecting objects.

Comment: @PseudoDruid I think that starting from a position of 'spells do only what they say they do' is correct, but you can be descriptivist or prescriptivist in your interpretation of what they 'say' they do. I encourage you to read the answers and comments on ['there is no flavor in spells'](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78012/is-there-flavor-text-in-dd-5e-spells) - a spell can _imply_ what it does without stating it directly. As for hazards, brown mold is not an object because it is _animate_ - it grows in response to heat. Similarly, green slime 'drops'; yellow mold 'ejects spores.' 1/2

Comment: @PseudoDruid 2/2 I think you are correct, however, that the _cone of cold_ produces an effect that deals cold damage and that this is sufficient to destroy the brown mold indirectly.  I have removed this from my answer; thank you for accepting it.

Answer (score 13):

#### Strictly RAW, no, it can't, and yes, that's stupid, so ignore it

*Cone of Cold* strictly damages creatures. The wall is not a creature, so it can't deal cold damage to it.

That's what the rules say anyway. The rules are wrong, and any DM worth their salt would ignore them in this, and any other case, where a spell dealing damage based on physical effects that are not specific to biological targets (e.g. psychic or poison damage) technically targets only creatures. I get they don't want *Cone of Cold* to destroy everyone's gear, but it's equally stupid to pretend it only affects creatures. The fire spells all specify they ignite flammable objects that aren't worn or carried; they really should have had this caveat for *all* spells that should logically damage objects too (non-poison, non-psychic), so they deal damage to unattended objects, to avoid stupid end results like this one.

Comment: Historical factoid: Ernie Gygax came up with the Cone of Cold spell specifically so it would not damage gear (as his father, Gary, had a great time burning magic items on foes when they were fireballed, and then telling the players about it). Ernie would kill them with Cone, then put the frozen corpses in a bag of holding to slowly  thew them out and retrive their treasure unharmed.

Comment: That historic fact might explain why it is 2 levels higher than fireball but barely (if at all give it is CON vs DEX) better.