# What spells can damage objects?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, objects

I know that only specific spells can damage objects (*fire bolt*, *fireball*, *shatter*, etc.).

Is there a list of possible spells that could target an object?

I found [this list of spells that can target objects on a person](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150601/what-methods-exist-to-damage-or-destroy-worn-or-carried-objects); however, there should be more that can target some objects that are not held or carried.

Comment: Needs clarity on what "damage" means in this context. For example are spells that can drop objects ok? How about any spell that creates fire? What about spells that create/manipulate water? Or are you only interested in spells that can deal damage to objects?

Comment: As @Non-novelist says, there is an incongruency here - the title asks for spells that _damage_ objects, while the body asks for spells that _target_ them.  It is impossible to give a correct answer without knowing what the question is.

Answer (score 9):

- Catapult
- Fire Bolt
- Heat Metal
- Shatter
- Storm of Vengeance Concentration
- Disintegrate
- Fireball
- Lightning Bolt
- Delayed Blast Fireball
- Meteor Swarm
- Wish
- Bigby's Hand
- Chain Lightning
- Acid Arrow
- Mordenkainen’s Sword
- Scorching Ray

Comment: I grabbed these by using google to search, obviously this is just a start.

Comment: Animate Objects is another one, albeit in an odd manner. Up to you if it's worth adding. The spell states "when the animated object drops to 0 hit points, it reverts to its original object form, and any remaining damage carries over to its original object form."

Comment: @Pepijn This has been made a community wiki, so it invites changes if you think there's a good candidate. Personally I would not, as the damage will be done by whoever fights with the object. I guess you could animate something you wanted broken and make it attack someone who didn't want it broken, which would be a fun story if nothing else.

Comment: Chain Lightning but not Lightning Bolt. Interesting.

Comment: @MichaelW. That Lightning Bolt is absent is an omission. It includes the line "The lightning ignites flammable objects in the area that aren't being worn or carried.", just like Fireball does include "The fire spreads around corners. It ignites flammable objects in the area that aren't being worn or carried."

Answer (score 6):

### Here is a list of *wizard* spells

This is covering the core rules (Players Handbook) only.

The first sublist contains spells that can ***damage or transform*** objects, counting those that set objects on fire as damaging.

You can see there's a pattern that mostly spells that deal **fire**, **thunder** or **electricity** damage can damage objects; plus there are a few that allow you to **attack** objects to damage them. You could interpret this more widely to include *Animate Dead* and have the undead attack the object, or *Suggestion*, and have the target attack the object, the list only covers spells more directly doing this.

### Damaging Objects

- Cantrip: **Fire Bolt**
- Level 1: **Burning Hands**
- Level 1: **Thunderwave**
- Level 2: **Acid Arrow**
- Level 2: **Flaming Sphere**
- Level 2: **Shatter**
- Level 2: **Scorching Ray**
- Level 3: **Fireball**
- Level 3: **Lightning Bolt**
- Level 4: **Control Water** (objects in whirlpool)
- Level 4: **Fabricate** (borderline, transform raw material objects)
- Level 5: **Animate Objects** (by attacking, also take damage)
- Level 5: **Bigby's Hand** (by striking)
- Level 5: **Telekinesis** (by dropping)
- Level 6: **Chain Lightning**
- Level 6: **Disintegrate**
- Level 7: **Delayed Blast Fireball**
- Level 7: **Fire Storm**
- Level 7: **Mordenkainen's Sword** (by attacking)
- Level 7: **Reverse Gravity** (by falling)
- Level 9: **Meteor Swarm**
- Level 9: **Storm of Vengeance**
- Level 9: **True Polymorph** (transform)
- Level 9: **Wish**

This second sublist contains other spells that can ***target objects***. It includes spells like *Identify* that require the caster to touch an object or like *Locate Object* that make him choose or describe one, without using the explicit wording of "target". It does not include spells such as *Faery Fire* that affect all objects in an area without damaging or targeting them.

### Targeting Objects

- **Light**
- **Mage Hand**
- **Mending**
- **Prestidigitation**
- **Identify**
- **Arcane Lock**
- **Continual Flame**
- **Darkness**
- **Enlarge/Reduce**
- **Heat Metal**
- **Knock**
- **Levitate**
- **Locate Object**
- **Magic Mouth**
- **Nystul's Magic Aura**
- **Daylight**
- **Dispel Magic**
- **Glyph of Warding**
- **Meld into Stone**
- **Nondetection**
- **Remove Curse**
- **Otiluke's Resilient Sphere**
- **Stone Shape** (changing shape but not outright transforming)
- **Legend Lore**
- **Drawmij's Instant Summons**
- **Sequester**
- **Symbol**
- **Teleport**
- **Antipathy/Sympathy**